# Need to improve performance when searching a custom object and returning it to a new collection

Tags: c#, performance, linq, observablecollection

The results are here:

```
Search Started: 9/20/2020 6:05:39 AM
Search Completed: Took 00:00:00
Collection Created: Took -00:01:18.4322494
DataSource Created: Took 00:00:00
```

What Im trying to do is search through a collection of objects for any that match a search term.  The collection is used as a binding datasource for a datagridview in a winforms app.  After the collection has been searched via linq, it returns the results back to an ObservableCollection and then sets it as the new datasource.  Everything works fine except the `SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<OrderLine>(SearchResultsQuery);` is VERY slow as you can see from the benchmark I did earlier.

Any help is appreciated!!

The Code that produced those results is here:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"Search Started: {startTime}");
SearchTerm = SearchTerm.ToUpper();

var SearchResultsQuery = from orderLine in new ObservableCollection<OrderLines.OrderLine>(OrderLineCollection)
                         where ( orderLine.BatchNumber != null && orderLine.BatchNumber.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.BatchStatus != null && orderLine.BatchStatus.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.CustomerItem != null && orderLine.CustomerItem.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.CustomerName != null && orderLine.CustomerName.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.CustomerPurchaseOrder != null && orderLine.CustomerPurchaseOrder.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.FGItem != null && orderLine.FGItem.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.IngItem != null && orderLine.IngItem.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.RawItem != null && orderLine.RawItem.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.ItemDescription != null && orderLine.ItemDescription.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Machine != null && orderLine.Machine.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.NextPONumber != null && orderLine.NextPONumber.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Note != null && orderLine.Note.Content.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.OrderNumber != null && orderLine.OrderNumber.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Status_1 != null && orderLine.Status_1.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Status_2 != null && orderLine.Status_2.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Status_3 != null && orderLine.Status_3.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Status_4 != null && orderLine.Status_4.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) ) ||
                         ( orderLine.Status_Today != null && orderLine.Status_Today.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchTerm) )
                         select orderLine;

TimeSpan searchTime = startTime - DateTime.Now;
startTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"Search Completed: Took {searchTime}");

SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<OrderLine>(SearchResultsQuery); //THIS LINE IS SLOW

TimeSpan collectionTime = startTime - DateTime.Now;
startTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"Collection Created: Took {collectionTime}");

bs.DataSource = SearchResults;

TimeSpan dataSourceTime = startTime - DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"DataSource Created: Took {dataSourceTime}");
```

How can I improve the performance of leading the LINQ results into a new collection?

Comment: it´s not that line which is slow. This is just because the query is **deferred** until it is needed. Having said this you should optimize the query, which I fear is where we can´t help you much. When you need to compare so many values you sure have to  fetch all of them.

Comment: Ahh ok I understand thank you.  Ill try and trim down the amount of values being queried.  Thank you for being an early bird like me.

Comment: How large is your database.  The query took over a minute.  The time is dependent on the size of the database and the type of database.  If you have a 100M database and you are using a file for the database it is going to be slow.  A database like SQL Server is designed to work with large files.  But if you are reading a csv file using oledb you are going to get slow results.  You cannot optimize your query.  To get faster results you have to use a better database or defrag your current database.

Comment: Great point.  It not a database its an ObservableCollection that holds objects called OrderLine.  OrderLine has about 25 properties, some of which are complex but most are just DateTime or strings.  Im not including the complex properties that require additional querying each in this query though.

Comment: why do you query an `Observable` at all and not just your actual datastore? What´s the point in wrapping `OrderLineCollection` into an `OberservableCollection`?

Comment: One approach you could consider is to add a `Search` method `orderLine`. Then, assuming you are using something like https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged, have an additional string property in the type which is the **concatenation of all of the values**. Thus, as the values in the instance change - the new property is kept up to date. Done this way, the `Search` can be done on a _single_ property (at the expense of keeping that new property up to date).

Comment: `new ObservableCollection<OrderLines.OrderLine>(OrderLineCollection)` What happens if you change that to `OrderLineCollection`?

Comment: The new collection was because I was attempting to run it in a separate thread to give the illusion of performance.  Ill give the single parameter idea a try, thank you

Comment: `The new collection was because I was attempting to run it in a separate thread to give the illusion of performance.` It did not run it on a separate thread. It slowed it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to consider:

Never use `DateTime` for measuring performance. Always use a stopwatch or benchmark.net. And never measure the first run of a algorithm, since it will include compilation time.

Another recommendation is to use a more [detailed profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019) that can provide line by line performance reports.

> new ObservableCollection(SearchResultsQuery); //THIS LINE IS SLOW

this is slow since this is the actual line running the query. Nothing abnormal about this.

> new ObservableCollection<OrderLines.OrderLine>(OrderLineCollection)

You should be able to just search thru the `OrderLineCollection`. Why are you copying everything to a `ObservableCollection`?

If many of the properties are strings, why are you running `.ToString()` on them?

`.ToUpper()` is quite inefficient since it has to create a new string, unfortenatly `.Contains` do not have an overload that takes a `StringComparison` parameter. Some suggest using .IndexOf, but this seem slower than `.Contains` when I test it.

One option would be to concatenate all the properties to a large string, a downside with this would be that the result could be different, Searching for "abcd" would be true if one property ends with "ab" and one begins with "cd". This may or not matter for your use case.

Another option would be to convert all the properties to a list of strings as a pre-process step, so searching would simply check all items in the list. This seem a bit slower than concatenating the properties.

Both of the above could be combined with `.AsParallel()` to run the query on multiple threads.

Third option would be to use something like [lucene](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) that is specifically made for fast searching.

When I do something similar I get about 700ms with the original code on 1000000 items. And about 15ms using string concatenation and AsParallel, (not including concatenating the strings). That should be sufficient for interactive performance. If you have many more items you might want to some third party solution for searching.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed response.  I will give these ideas a try, namely the single string parameter and then user .AsParallel() which is not something I'm familiar with but it looks like I'm about to be.